# when i use sendMessage() method to send message in chat when i am using telegram bot in group automatically reply last message

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

when i use sendMessage() method to send message in chat when i am using telegram bot in group automatically reply last message
how can i solve this?

[enter image description here][1]

```
function Start($obj_tblTemp, $Token) {
    $Keyboard = array(
        'keyboard' => array(
            array(INSERT_EXPENSE, DELETE_EXPENSE),
            array(EXPENSE_SITUATION, RULES_AND_HELP),
            array(CANCEL)
            )
        );
    $Key_board = json_encode($Keyboard);
    $url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $Token . '/sendMessage?text='. $obj_tblTemp->get_message() . '&chat_id=' . $obj_tblTemp->get_chat_Id() . '&reply_markup=' . $Key_board;
    file_get_contents($url);
}
```

also above problem exist in below function:

```
function InsertExpenseMode($obj_tblTemp, $Token, $con, $obj_tblTempLatestSession) {
if ($obj_tblTemp->get_message() == INSERT_EXPENSE) {
    $url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $Token . '/sendMessage?text='
            . INSERT_EXPENSE_INSTRUCTION . '&chat_id=' . $obj_tblTemp->get_chat_Id();
    file_get_contents($url);
} else {
    if (is_numeric($obj_tblTemp->get_message()) && $obj_tblTemp->get_message() > 0) {
        $url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $Token . '/sendMessage?text='
                . $obj_tblTemp->get_message() . '&chat_id=' . $obj_tblTemp->get_chat_Id();
        file_get_contents($url);
    } else {
        $url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $Token . '/sendMessage?text='
                . NUMERAL_FAIL . '&chat_id=' . $obj_tblTemp->get_chat_Id();
        file_get_contents($url);
    }
}
```

}

actually i send class objects to these function and want to evaluate user inputs then insert them to database, but development wasn't completed yet.

Comment: Because you're using `$obj_tblTemp->get_message()` to get the last message?. You should post more code to have a complete view of how your code works

Comment: thank you so much for answering, i changed my question as above, hope was fine.